# Rendering a nested partial template - to rended a nested form on a two separate models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, nested-forms, partials

I'm on week two of this issue and have recently used the railsCast  [#196 (revised)](https://github.com/railscasts/196-nested-model-form-revised). I know this is older - maybe that's my issue. As an extra spin I'm hosting my rails server off Cloud 9.

I've tried following a few different tutorials just to get one going & this is as far as I've gotten. The weird part is none of their syntex matches what the official ruby on rails documentation has ... Rails View templates.

In the railsCast the guy is able to get blank fields to show up ... I'm not sure how...so I haven't managed to populate the question or answer fields yet.  I'm not even sure what the two rails console messages mean - besides there aren't records there to be had.

Thanks for reading & any suggestions!

-M

Without further ado, my senario ... nested forms via templates as shown in railsCast 196 ...

My rails console ...

```
2.2.1 :045 >   cc = Survey.first.questions.first
  Survey Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "surveys".* FROM "surveys"  ORDER BY "surveys"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."survey_id" = ?  ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["survey_id", 1]]
 => nil 
2.2.1 :046 > cc = Survey.first.questions
  Survey Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "surveys".* FROM "surveys"  ORDER BY "surveys"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."survey_id" = ?  [["survey_id", 1]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

My terminal console log ...

```
Started GET "/surveys/5/edit" for 68.54.21.200 at 2015-11-27 02:46:48 +0000
Cannot render console from 68.54.21.200! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by SurveysController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"5"}
  Survey Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "surveys".* FROM "surveys" WHERE "surveys"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Question Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."survey_id" = ?  [["survey_id", 5]]
  Rendered surveys/_form.html.erb (4.2ms)
  Rendered surveys/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (7.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 70ms (Views: 67.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

So my code ...

surveys_controller.rb

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @surveys = Survey.all
  end

  def show
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    3.times do
      question = @survey.questions.build
      4.times { question.answers.build }
    end
  end

  def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)
    if @survey.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created survey."
      redirect_to @survey
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    if @survey.update_attributes(params[:survey])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated survey."
      redirect_to @survey
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    @survey.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed survey."
    redirect_to surveys_url
  end

  private
  def survey_params
    params.required(:survey).permit(:id, :survey, :notice)

  end

end
```

Edit action view

```
<% title = "Edit Survey" %>

<%= render 'form' %>

<p>
  <%= link_to "Show", @survey %> |
  <%= link_to "View All", surveys_path %>
</p>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
  <% if @survey.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@survey.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this survey from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @survey.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

 <% f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
    <%= render "question_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>

  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

_question_fields.html.erb

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :content, "Question" %><br />
  <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %><br />
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Question" %>
</p>
<% f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
  <%= render 'answer_fields', :f => builder %>

<% end %>
```

_answer_fields.html.erb

```
<p>
  <%= f.label :content, "Answer" %>
  <%= f.text_field :content %>
  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
  <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove" %>
</p>
```

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a suggestion. Use "cocoon" gem for nested forms. It's easy to implement and had a good documentation.

Comment: I'll spin off another instance of it and fork github, but I'd really like to understand enough about the rails trouble shooting that I can walk through the "magic" of rails myself - I don't want to be a copypasta webdev :)

Comment: No success yet - I forked my work on github & am going to less complicated things ... using a partial being rendered to display a string would be the next test.  After I know that works, then I'm going to create scaffold the author of railsCast didn't make to fill in values on the other models - in case it's an empty field issue (I don't think ruby on rails is that primitive, but as a programmer we have to test all theories right?).

Comment: Code is looking good. How do your models look? Do you have the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each of the 7 projects I ran off the web...

It was the nesting of the array's within the params.require() that was the problem..  It's one thing to tell someone it has to be nested - it's another to show them the syntax when they are new :)

Example:

```
// Note this is from memory, as I deleted this version of the github..so it's not exactly right or tested...

params.require(:survey).permit(:id,:questions => [:id, :survey_id, :question, :answers => [:id, :question_id, :answer]])
```

Here's the break down of that same example in depth:

```
params.require(:survey).permit(
   :id,    
   :questions => [:id, // This is the 1st nesting
       :survey_id, :question, :answers => [:id, // This is 1st nested array ":questions"
       :question_id, :answer]   // End the 2nd nested array ":answers"
    ] // End the 2nd array ":questions"
 )  // End the ":surveys" array & the .permit as a whole
```